# How to read embedded html string in js?

Tags: javascript, html, html-parsing

I have a string, which needs to be converted to a readable form. Expected output is attached at the bottom. This is basically reading `html` string in js. I have gone through various articles but didn't quite find any thing.

```
str = "<p><!-- [if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
  <o:AllowPNG/>
 </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml><![endif]--> <!-- [if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:WordDocument>
  <w:View>Normal</w:View>
  <w:PunctuationKerning/>
  <w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>false</w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>
  <w:DoNotPromoteQF/>
  <w:LidThemeOther>EN-GB</w:LidThemeOther>
  <w:LidThemeAsian>ZH-CN</w:LidThemeAsian>
  <w:LidThemeComplexScript>AR-SA</w:LidThemeComplexScript>
  <w:Compatibility>
   <w:BreakWrappedTables/>
   <w:OverrideTableStyleHps/>
  </w:Compatibility>
  <m:mathPr>
   <m:mathFont m:val="Cambria Math"/>
   <m:brkBin m:val="before"/>
   Name="index heading"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="35" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="caption"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="table of figures"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="envelope address"/>
   Name="Table Columns 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Table Columns 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Table Columns 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Table Columns 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Table Columns 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Table Grid 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Table Grid 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Table Grid 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Table Grid 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Table Grid 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Table Grid 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Table Grid 7"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Table Grid 8"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Table List 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Table List 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Table List 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Table List 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Table List 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Table List 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Table List 7"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Table List 8"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Table 3D effects 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Table 3D effects 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Table 3D effects 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Table Contemporary"/>
   Name="Table Web 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Balloon Text"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="Table Grid"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Table Theme"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" Name="Placeholder Text"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="1" QFormat="true" Name="No Spacing"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="49" Name="List Table 4 Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="50" Name="List Table 5 Dark Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="51"
   Name="List Table 6 Colorful Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="52"
   Name="List Table 7 Colorful Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Mention"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Smart Hyperlink"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Hashtag"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Unresolved Mention"/>
 </w:LatentStyles>
</xml><![endif]--></p>
<h3 class="MsoNormal" style="margin-top: 0px; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 13px; background-color: #ffffff; margin-bottom: 5px !important;">&nbsp;</h3>
<h3><img src="http://lms-286-liveshared.edcastcloud.com:80/asset-v1:thomson-foundation+6663jn04+self-paced+type@asset+block@CPDtick.jpg" alt="" width="116" height="106" /></h3>
<p>This course carries&nbsp;4 hours of Continuing Professional Development (CPD) credits.&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>In support of the Journalism Now Scholar Programme, for a limited time, there is no charge for the course certificate.&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong style="font-size: 14px;">COURSE OVERVIEW</strong><span style="font-size: 14px;">&nbsp;</span></p>
<p>This course will help give your use of social media a journalistic purpose.&nbsp; You'll learn how to find good stories, whether you're using Facebook, Twitter, Instagram, or any other form of social media. Once you've completed the course, you will be able to understand each of the social media platforms - they all have their own system which you will be able to get to grips with and you will discover how to refine your searches so that you get the information you need more easily.&nbsp; The course will help you become a good 'social listener' by giving you the best hashtags to use, as well as the best keywords.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>"<em>The content is really good, I enjoyed it because I went in without knowing much but finished the course more knowledgeable. I learnt a lot of things.</em>" <strong>Pheladi from South Africa</strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>WHAT YOU WILL LEARN</strong></p>
<p>&bull; How to use SOCIAL MEDIA to FOLLOW breaking news and to FIND STORIES as well as sources.&nbsp;</p>
<p>&bull; How to use ADVANCED SEARCH TECHNIQUES as a tool for finding information and locating experts.</p>
<p>&bull; How to use social media to verify if a BREAKING NEWS story is true.</p>
<p>&bull; How to establish the ORIGIN OF PHOTOGRAPHS and how to verify them.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>MEET YOUR INSTRUCTORS</strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;<img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://lms-286-liveshared.edcastcloud.com:80/asset-v1:thomson-foundation+6663jn04+self-paced+type@asset+block@JN04_-_Trainer.png" alt="" width="387" height="217" /></p>
<p><strong>SUE LLEWELLYN</strong> is your course instructor. For the past 10 years, Sue has worked as a trainer for thousands of journalists, teaching them how to use social media. Before that, she was a journalist for 15 years in the BBC Newsroom.&nbsp;</p>
<p>&emsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;<img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://lms-286-liveshared.edcastcloud.com:80/asset-v1:thomson-foundation+6663jn04+self-paced+type@asset+block@JN04_-_Experts.jpeg" alt="" width="387" height="129" /></p>
<p>Helping Sue is a team of experts (from left to right):</p>
<ul>
<li><strong>Matt Cooke</strong> works at the Google News Lab, Matt is an ex-BBC newsman who is a specialist in digital storytelling.&nbsp;</li>
<li><strong>Anne-Marie Tomchak</strong> is the former presenter of BBC Trending who's now UK editor of Mashable.&nbsp;</li>
<li><strong>Fred Mwasa</strong> is Deputy Editor-in-Chief at Kigali Today.&nbsp; Fred has a massive following on Twitter, with the highest number of followers for journalists in Rwanda.&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>COURSE OUTLINE</strong>&nbsp;</p>
<p>The course is divided into four sections:</p>
<ul>
<li><strong style="font-family: inherit; font-size: 1rem;">Section 1</strong><span style="font-family: inherit; font-size: 1rem;"> provides an overview and introduces the course instructor and media experts</span></li>
<li><strong style="font-family: inherit; font-size: 1rem;">Section 2</strong><span style="font-family: inherit; font-size: 1rem;"> explains the use of different social media platforms as sources for newsgathering.</span></li>
<li><strong style="font-family: inherit; font-size: 1rem;">Section 3</strong><span style="font-family: inherit; font-size: 1rem;"> demonstrates how advanced search techniques in Google can be used for newsgathering.</span></li>
<li><strong style="font-family: inherit; font-size: 1rem;">Section 4</strong><span style="font-family: inherit; font-size: 1rem;"> is the course summary.</span></li>
</ul>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>HOW TO PASS:</strong></p>
<p>You will be presented with a practical exercise based on the concepts discussed which you will need to complete together with your feedback.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>TIME COMMITMENT</strong></p>
<p>You can complete this course within 4 hours over multiple sessions.</p>"
```

How to read this string to generate the expected output.

I tried this but doesn't quite work. I doesn't replace `Enter` character from the string.

```
str = str.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, '');
```

Expected Output :

```
This course carries&nbsp;4 hours of Continuing Professional Development (CPD) credits.&nbsp;
&nbsp;
In support of the Journalism Now Scholar Programme, for a limited time, there is no charge for the course certificate.&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;
COURSE OVERVIEW&nbsp;
This course will help give your use of social media a journalistic purpose.&nbsp; You'll learn how to find good stories, whether you're using Facebook, Twitter, Instagram, or any other form of social media. Once you've completed the course, you will be able to understand each of the social media platforms - they all have their own system which you will be able to get to grips with and you will discover how to refine your searches so that you get the information you need more easily.&nbsp; The course will help you become a good 'social listener' by giving you the best hashtags to use, as well as the best keywords.
&nbsp;
"The content is really good, I enjoyed it because I went in without knowing much but finished the course more knowledgeable. I learnt a lot of things." Pheladi from South Africa
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
WHAT YOU WILL LEARN
&bull; How to use SOCIAL MEDIA to FOLLOW breaking news and to FIND STORIES as well as sources.&nbsp;
&bull; How to use ADVANCED SEARCH TECHNIQUES as a tool for finding information and locating experts.
&bull; How to use social media to verify if a BREAKING NEWS story is true.
&bull; How to establish the ORIGIN OF PHOTOGRAPHS and how to verify them.
&nbsp;
MEET YOUR INSTRUCTORS
&nbsp;
SUE LLEWELLYN is your course instructor. For the past 10 years, Sue has worked as a trainer for thousands of journalists, teaching them how to use social media. Before that, she was a journalist for 15 years in the BBC Newsroom.&nbsp;
&emsp;
&nbsp;
Helping Sue is a team of experts (from left to right):

Matt Cooke works at the Google News Lab, Matt is an ex-BBC newsman who is a specialist in digital storytelling.&nbsp;
Anne-Marie Tomchak is the former presenter of BBC Trending who's now UK editor of Mashable.&nbsp;
Fred Mwasa is Deputy Editor-in-Chief at Kigali Today.&nbsp; Fred has a massive following on Twitter, with the highest number of followers for journalists in Rwanda.&nbsp;

&nbsp;
COURSE OUTLINE&nbsp;
The course is divided into four sections:

Section 1 provides an overview and introduces the course instructor and media experts
Section 2 explains the use of different social media platforms as sources for newsgathering.
Section 3 demonstrates how advanced search techniques in Google can be used for newsgathering.
Section 4 is the course summary.

&nbsp;
HOW TO PASS:
You will be presented with a practical exercise based on the concepts discussed which you will need to complete together with your feedback.
&nbsp;
TIME COMMITMENT
You can complete this course within 4 hours over multiple sessions."
```

Comment: So you're looking for help w your regExp? Maybe you should add the tag. What character do you mean by `Enter`?

Comment: Yes regExp, Enter means \n here.

Comment: That's commonly known as a new-line. Why don't you just add `\n` to the regExp?

Comment: Did but it doesn't generate the expected output. Is there any other way apart from regex ?

Comment: Have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript), which might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved it using this Regex:

`description.replace(/(<!--.*?-->)|(<!--[\w\W\n\s]+?-->)|<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, '');`